# SelectedItem in Dropdown is calling twice in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a drop down in my xamarin forms app with months. When the page loading initially I am getting data from a network call according to the current month which is getting from the drop down. Then I also have the function to load data by changing month in the drop down. My problem is in the initial page loading the data is getting doubled. **SelectedItem** is calling twice.

My View Model...

```
            public LeadMgtSmVM(string uType)
            {
                checkVisibility(uType);

                SelectedItem = getCurrentMonth();
            }

            private MonthData getCurrentMonth()
            {

                int intCurrentMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
                string name = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(intCurrentMonth);

                for (int i = 1; i <= intCurrentMonth; i++)
                {

                    MyList.Add(new MonthData { mName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i) });

                }

                return new MonthData { mName = name };

            }

            public MonthData SelectedItem
            {
                get => _selectedItem;
                set
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;

                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        int month = DateTime.ParseExact(_selectedItem.ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
                        sMonth = month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
                        currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

                        IsBusy = true;
                        await getSMLeadData(Settings.userBranch, currentYear, sMonth);
                        IsBusy = false;

                    });

                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }

            }

      private async Task getSMLeadData(string uBranch, string currentYear, string sMonth)
            {

                string sList = await _apiServices.getSmTargetData(uBranch, currentYear, sMonth, authenticateData);
                var mList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeadMgtSM_Data>(sList);

}
```

XAML....

```
                        <input:Dropdown Title="Month"
                        TitleColor="Black"     
                        AnnotationColor="Accent" 
                        IsRequired="True"                             
                        TextColor="#565656"
                        BorderColor="Black" 
                        Color="Orange"         
                        PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                        Placeholder="Choose one" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

MyList...

```
 public IList<MonthData> MyList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MonthData>();
```

MonthData ...

```
public class MonthData
{
    public string mName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => mName;
}
```

Comment: How does `MyList` look like?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: is "Dropdown" a custom render for the Picker?, or is it a pluging that i don't know of

Comment: it is "Plugin.InputKit"